# MySQL calculate difference in count column between two queries

Tags: mysql, count, subtraction

I have two different queries.  One for "plus" and one for "minus".  I want to find the difference in the count value for each player.

I tried union all and got some very weird numbers.

Here are the results of each query which I ned to find the difference of:

```
fk_plus_player1_id  cnt
90                  71
65                  68
79                  66
45                  59
64                  57
27                  56
55                  56
93                  55
37                  55
40                  44
 1                  36
84                  33
20                  31
24                  28
 8                  23


fk_minus_player1_id cnt
93                  44
64                  42
79                  40
37                  35
90                  33
20                  31
84                  31
27                  30
65                  30
40                  26
 1                  26
24                  25
45                  25
55                  22
 8                  10
```

How would I accomplish this?  Thanks in advance for your help.  I am a noob...

UGH...Trying to do the join method.  Having issues, getting no results, just 4 empty columns.  This is what I am trying

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  (
    SELECT
        statement for plus results here
  ) AS tp
  JOIN (
    SELECT
        statement for minus results here
  ) AS tm ON tp.fk_plus_player1_id = tm.fk_minus_player1_id
GROUP BY
    fk_plus_player1_id
```

suggestions??

Comment: you need to join the records based on the keys, then do the math.  This site can help you understand join syntax. http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two tables.
You want for each player, the difference of the counts.

So :

```
SELECT t1.fk_minus_player1_id AS player, ABS(t1.cnt - t2.cnt) AS difference
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
WHERE t1.fk_minus_player1_id = t2.fk_plus_player1_id
GROUP BY t1.fk_minus_player1_id;
```

Maybe this is what you're looking for ?

```
WITH query1 AS 
(SELECT t1.fk_minus_player1_id AS player, (t1.cnt - IFNULL(t2.cnt,0)) AS difference
FROM table1 t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.fk_minus_player1_id = t2.fk_plus_player1_id
GROUP BY t1.fk_minus_player1_id), 
query2 AS (SELECT t2.fk_plus_player1_id AS player, (IFNULL(t1.cnt,0) - t2.cnt) AS difference
FROM table2 t2 LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 t1 ON t1.fk_minus_player1_id = t2.fk_plus_player1_id
GROUP BY t2.fk_plus_player1_id)

(SELECT player, difference
FROM query1)

UNION

(SELECT player, difference 
FROM query2 WHERE player NOT IN (SELECT player FROM query1))
```

Comment: Hi @davidk.  I have been playing with your suggestion and it only provides a single row instead of a row with every player.  Also, there is the possibility that a players calculated number will be and should be negative.  Thanks for any other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You run the risk that the same players are not in both lists.  The solution is `union all` with `group by`:

```
select player1id, sum(pluscnt) as pluscnt, sum(minuscnt) as minuscnt,
       (sum(pluscnt) - sum(minuscnt)) as diff
from ((select player1id, cnt as pluscnt, 0 as minuscnt
       from plustable
      ) union all
      (select player1id, 0, cnt
       from minustable
      )
     ) t
group by player1id;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon.  I have the same list issue figured out in the original queries.  A player will be zero if they don't otherwise have a number.  does that simplify your code?

Comment: That means that you could use a `join` instead.  Because MySQL doesn't offer a `full outer join`, you run the risk of losing a player in one subquery or the other, if s/he were to be missing from result set.